# Ubuntu 18.04 desktop: netplan.io+NetworkManager: wrong default route mask (0.0.0.0/24)

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-bridge, netplan

My yaml file is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.245.50/24]
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.204.35/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.4,192.168.1.5]
        search: [mydomain.xyz]
        routes:
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: 192.168.204.1
            metric: 200
            type: unicast
```

After 'netplan apply' command i get the wrong route mask (0.0.0.0/**24**):

```
$ sudo ip route
0.0.0.0/24 via 192.168.204.1 dev br0 proto static metric 200 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.204.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.204.35 metric 425 linkdown 
192.168.245.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.245.50 metric 100
$ sudo ip route del 0.0.0.0/24
$ sudo ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.204.1 dev br0 proto static metric 200
$ sudo ip route
default via 192.168.204.1 dev br0 proto static metric 200 
....
```

When I specify the correct route (see above), the interface goes up and the network becomes available. After reboot the wrong route appears again.

What to do?

Comment: You have to do a `sudo netplan --debug generate` before the `sudo netplan apply`. But you probably should be using networkd instead of NetworkManager. Is this a server? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Hi,  @heynnema! I use desktop version. Execution of `sudo netplan --debug generate` before the `sudo netplan apply` don't take effect. @Yuri Fedkin

Answer (score 0):

**Notes:**

Check the gateway4 address and DNS nameserver/search values that I used. I'm not sure if having them on different subnets from the main IP addresses will cause DNS resolution errors.

If you don't need the bridge, you can move the **addresses**: and **routes**: stanza's directly into **enp2s0** (*under dhcp6*), and remove the **bridges**: section. Be mindful of the indentation.

If you copy/paste the script, you **may** need to remove the leading 4 spaces from each line. This is because when I use the `{} code sample` to make the script readable, it adds 4 spaces to the beginning of each line. Keep the indentation the same.

If you don't have any wireless interfaces, you may need to change **NetworkManager** to **networkd**.

Use https://netplan.io/examples for more examples.

After installing the script (*as the only .yaml file*) into `/etc/netplan` do:

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

---

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.4,192.168.1.5]
        search: [mydomain.xyz]
      optional: true
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.245.50/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.245.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.4,192.168.1.5]
        search: [mydomain.xyz]
      optional: true
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      addresses: [192.168.204.35/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.204.1
          metric: 200
          type: unicast
```

Comment: Hi, @heynnema! When I apply your yaml script and reboot PC I've got linkdown state for `br0` interface and `0.0.0.0/24` as default route.

Comment: Do you have wireless networks on this machine? Did you remove the leading 4 spaces from each line, if that was required? Did you keep the indentation the same? Did the generate command issue any errors?

Comment: I think that this problem lies in NetworkManager area. Wheh I run `nm-connection-editor` choose `br0` interface and click on routes button on IPv4-tab I see error on route. The cell with address 0.0.0.0 is marked with red color and mask is set to 255.255.255.0. When i try to correct mask to 0.0.0.0 the cell becames red, too.

Comment: I haven't any wi-fi interface. As you see above I follow to indent recomendations.

Comment: @YuriFedkin first, try changing **NetworkManager** to **networkd**, redo the two netplan commands, and see if that helps. Second, if that doesn't help, you can try moving the addresses and routes from br0 to enp2s0, right under the dhcp6 line. Report back, and I can edit the answer if either change works.

Comment: I 've tried to move the addresses and routes from br0 to enp2s0. It's not work.

Comment: I run `netplan apply` and then put `less /run/NetworkManager/system-connections/netplan-br0`. The route in this file is correct. This confirms my assumption that the bug in the NM.

Comment: Remember that you have to do a netplan generate before the apply. Did you try changing **NetworkManager** to **networkd**? That takes NM out of the picture.

Comment: Hi, @heynnema! For `renderer: networkd`  it works for me fine. Thank you!

Comment: I use script published in my first message where i changed only `NetworkManager` to `networkd`. Sorry, your script version is not work for me.